# Вывести в цикле объект, где его свойства - массивы

Tags: javascript

Есть подобный объект с массивами

```
var section = {
  link: [],
  filename: [],
  name: [],
  author: [],
  material: [],
  scale: [],
  date: [],
  museum: [],
  city: [],
  notation: [],
};
```

Как можно перебрать его значения в цикле, чтобы вывести их (хочу заполнить таблицу). Делать вложенный цикл?
Почему этот цикл не работает?

```
for (property in section) {
  property['filename'].forEach(function(item) {
    alert(item);
  });
}
```

Comment: Ну чтобы проходить по внутренней коллекции каждого дочернего элемента вложенный цикл определенно должен быть

Comment: Может потому, что for...in возвращает ключ (или индекс) объекта, а не сам объект?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`property['filename']` - неверно в вашем случае, т.к. property уже ключ.

Попробуйте примерно так:

```
for (property in section) {
   section[property].forEach(function(item) {
     alert(item);
   });
}
```

P.S. подробнее про for...in [прочитайте](https://learn.javascript.ru/object-for-in)

Comment: Да, верно, спасибо! А как можно корректно вывести их в таблице?